# can i know if my app can start an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

since Android 10,  there are restrictions on starting activity:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

is there a way to know if my app can start an activity or need to display a notification?

my tests only show logcat message ActivityTaskManager: Background activity start

but there is no exception thrown...

is there a way to programmaticaly know if i can start an activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start activity from background you need to ask permission of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

It's runtime permission so user needs to allow it.

Try this it worked for me!

Comment: thank you for the tip, i will try. but as user can revoke/deny this permission, i still need to know if i can start an activity or need to display a notification...

Comment: You will need a notification ~ Foreground Service, without it you cannot do it. As Android has stopped spport for background service like the way you want to use it.